# XML (with namespace) to Object unmarshalling

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I got following repsonse from a Web service call, I tried to unmarshal the same using JAXB to map it to a java class. I was getting unmarshal exception while doing so.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:QueryByLNResponse xmlns:ns0="UIS_CTMPeople_WS" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:First_Name>Pradeep</ns0:First_Name>
        <ns0:Internet_E-mail/>
        <ns0:ManagersName/>
        <ns0:Person_ID>PPL1</ns0:Person_ID>
        <ns0:Last_Name>Srinivasa Reddy</ns0:Last_Name>
        <ns0:Full_Name>Pradeep M Srinivasa Reddy</ns0:Full_Name>
    </ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:First_Name>Geeth </ns0:First_Name>
        <ns0:Internet_E-mail>bas@yahoo.com</ns0:Internet_E-mail>
        <ns0:ManagersName/>
        <ns0:Person_ID>PPL2</ns0:Person_ID>
        <ns0:Last_Name>Srinivasan</ns0:Last_Name>
        <ns0:Full_Name>Geeth  Srinivasan</ns0:Full_Name>
    </ns0:getListValues>
</ns0:QueryByLNResponse>
```

I tried to unmarshal the above code using

```java
public static Object xmlToObject(String xml, Class... objClass) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(objClass);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    return unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
}
```

It was throwing following error

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"UIS_CTMPeople_WS", local:"QueryByLNeResponse"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
```

How can i unmarshalling this using JAXB ( xml to object ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are a few items that should help:

---

**NAMESPACES**

You should use a the `@XmlSchema` annotation on the `package-info` class to specify the namespace qualification.  Below is an example, you will need to change the package name to match your model.

***package-info.java***

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "UIS_CTMPeople_WS",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

**ROOT ELEMENTS**

It appears that you do not have any of your classes mapped with `@XmlRootElement` (or `@XmlElementDecl`).  I would expect you to have something like the following:

***QueryByLNResponse***

```
package example;

@XmlRootElement(name="QueryByLNResponse")
public class QueryByLNResponse {
}
```

Alternatively you could specify the class you wish to unmarshal to, by using one of the unmarshal methods that take a `Class` parameter:

```
return unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, QueryByLNResponse.class)
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

---

**PERFORMANCE**

In your same code you are creating a new `JAXBContext` each time you do an unmarshal.  `JAXBContext` is a thread safe object which can be created once and reused to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, I will give it a try & let you know about outcome

Comment: I have list of records(getListValues) under QueryByLNResponse root element, how i need to handle this in java

Comment: @user879870 - The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: No need to have setters & getters for properties if we use XML annotations?

Comment: @user879870 - Check out:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Your blogs are very much useful. I am a newbie to JAXB - really helping. I am still working on this one, if any issues I will post it here

Comment: Can you please have a look @ http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1742690, let me know where I did wrong

Comment: @user879870 - Is your package-info class in the same package as the rest of your domain model?  It doesn't seem to be getting picked up.

Comment: I have kept everything under same package & tried - got the same result. Java classes for reference http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1744064

Comment: @user879870 - unfortunately I don't have access to a computer until Saturday to try out your example (currently answering what I can from my phone.  Is the a chance the package-info class is not compiling?  I would also recommend to marshal your model to XML to get a sense of what the unmarshal is eXpecting.

Comment: It is working now, approach whatever you have mentioned is correct. Thank you